# Why does void loop() stop after some samples?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c, spi, signal-processing

I am not getting any compile time error. After some samples of data `void loop()` stops executing. Please let know what the problem is. Below is my code.

Thanks and regards
Thippeswamy

```
#include<SPI.h>
float amplitude=1.5;
int freq1=20; int freq2=12;
int k=20;float A= amplitude*k; 
int Fs=10550; float sine[5000]; float Fs1=3000;
int i=0;int reg1=1; int reg2=0;
int sample1=Fs/freq1; float sample2=Fs1/freq2;

void setup() {
  int SS=10; 
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin();  
}

void data(int reg, int data) {
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW);
  SPI.transfer(reg);
  SPI.transfer(data);
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  for(int j=0;j<sample1||i<sample2||i>=sample2);j++) {
    float s=A*sin((2*3.14*freq1*j)/Fs);
    sine[j]=s+190;
    data(reg1,sine[j]);
    if(i<=sample2) {
      float s=A*sin((2*3.14*freq2*i)/Fs1);
      sine[i]=s+190;
      data(reg2,sine[i]);
      i++;
    } else if(i>sample2) {
      float s=A*sin((2*3.14*freq2*i)/Fs1);
      sine[i]=s+190;
      data(reg2,sine[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please format your code properly (indent at least 4 spaces)

Comment: how do you know that the code stops?

Comment: I find it hard to believe you are not getting a compiler error because this line `for(int j=0;j<sample1||i<sample2||i>=sample2);j++)` has a bracket too many.

Comment: Also I really don't like the conditions used in that `if`... It looks like it's likely to end up with `j` being more than the size of your `sine[]` array since you have no absolute bounds checking...

Comment: Your huge `sine[]` array serves no useful purpose. Get rid of it and just `data(reg2, s + 190);`.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> float sine[5000]
> ...
> sine[j]=s+190;
> ```

A float takes 4 bytes. You are allocating 5000 of them which is 20000 bytes. The Uno has 2048 bytes of RAM. Thus you are running out of RAM and overwriting something you shouldn't be.

---

As pointed out on [the Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=520194), your `for` loop which tests for:

```
i < sample2 || i >= sample2
```

will always be true. Of course `i` will be *either* **less than** or **greater than or equal to** `sample2`.

Comment: Hi, Now i have chanced the data type to int and reduced the value to 1000, even now also same thing is happened

Comment: 1000 x 5 = 5000 which is still more than 2048.

Comment: On arduino.cc forum OP has the same question, only there he mentions Arduino Due http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=520194

Comment: See amended answer. Your `for` loop will never end.